# FireDac - как узнать ID транзакции?

Tags: delphi, firedac

При использовании библиотеки `FIBPlus` ID Транзакции можно получить конструкцией `TpFIBTransaction(Sender).TransactionID`

Чем заменить эту конструкцию при переходе на `FireDac`?

Comment: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Phys.IBWrapper.TIBTransaction.TransactionID

Comment: да, спасибо - есть такое. Но так как FireDac предоставляет доступ к разным БД(из-за чего и был выбран) хотелось бы понимать существует ли доступ к считыванию информации по TransactionID и для других БД? Заранее спасибо и за ответ на этот вопрос.

Comment: пожалуйста, рад был помочь

Comment: В других обёртках https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Phys такого не нашел

Comment: Для чего планируешь его использовать?

Comment: TransactionID нужен - для мониторинга запущеных транзакций. т.е. Есть приложение которое запускает кучу потоков - в этих потоках конект к БД и куча запросов каждый запрос отдаёт TID наверх - для того что бы через оболочку приложения можно было срубить Транзакцию - но не поток.

Comment: тогда возможно посоветуешь куда я могу задать данный вопрос разработчикам FireDac? - Насколько мне известно  - запрос к любой БД работает в контексте транзакций и было бы не "честно" ограничивать в этом TFDTransaction.

Comment: хм, необычное использование (не сталкивался с подобным ранее), по поводу вопроса разработчикам (это ж разработка Embarcadero, ни разу ни чего подобного не спрашивал у них, поэтому не подскажу, где именно подобные запросы им писать). возможно кто-то подскажет ещё что-нибудь по этому поводу. (может я что ни так посмотрел( )

Comment: Во многих СУБД в рамках коннекта может быть только одна транзакция. У нее нет собственного ID, есть только текущая транзакция указанного коннекта.

Comment: Да - есть такое "Во многих СУБД в рамках коннекта может быть только одна транзакция" - но в СУБД - эта транзакция всё-таки отслеживается.